# I am able to connect to the Hive database using pyspark but when i run my program data is not showing

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have written the below code to read the data from HIVE table and when I am trying to run no compilation errors and no data displaying.

```
   from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext, SparkSession
   import os 
   os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars hive-jdbc-2.1.0.jar   
   pyspark-shell'


   sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("App")
   sc = SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)
   sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
   hiveContext = HiveContext(sc);


   source_df = hiveContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
              url='jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/sample',
              driver='org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver',
              dbtable='abc',
              user='root',
              password='root').load()

   print source_df.show()


     When i run this, I am getting below output and not able to fetch the
    data from table.

    +--------+------+
   |abc.name|abc.id|
   +--------+------+
   +--------+------+
```

Comment: Can you not read the table directly without JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
df = hiveContext.read.table("your_hive_table") //reads from default db
df = hiveContext.read.table("your_db.your_hive_table") //reads from your db
```

you could also do

```
df = hiveContext.sql("select * from your_table")
```

Comment: I want to read it from the database created my own, Instead of reading it from the defaul db

Comment: Still the database is connecting but no data

Comment: How do i establish the connection, Before using this
df = hiveContext.sql("select * from your_table")